# jQuery .css() click change color with condition

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table and I'm using fadeToggle on the list to hide and show the table. The list background is green color but i want to change the list color when hiding the table and when i click to show the table it back to green color  but my code is not working.

```
<div class="main">
        <ul class="top_menu" >
            <li class="orderList" id="starter_li">Starter</li>
            <li class="orderList" id="soup_li"> Soup</li>
            <li class="orderList" id="seafood_li">Seafood</li>
            <li class="orderList" id="return_li">Return All</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="middleBox">
            <table class="food_table" id="starters" style="width:100%">
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>S1</td> 
                    <td>Starter1<br>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
        <table class="food_table" id="soups" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Soup1</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
         <table class="food_table" id="seafood" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>seafood1</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#starter_li").click(function(){
        $("#starters").fadeToggle(500);

        $(this).css("background-color","white");
        $(this).css("color","#05FF0A");

    });
        $("#soup_li").click(function(){
        $("#soups").fadeToggle(500);
        $(this).css("background-color","white");
        $(this).css("color","#05FF0A");
    });
        $("#seafood_li").click(function(){
        $("#seafoods").fadeToggle(500);
        $(this).css("background-color","white");
        $(this).css("color","#05FF0A");
      });
        $("#return_li").click(function(){
                $(".food_table").fadeIn(500);
        });


            $('.orderList').click(function(e){
            var color = $(this).css('background-color');
            if (color == 'white')
             $(this).css('background-color','#05FF0A');
         });
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

changing

`if (color == 'white')`

to

`if (color == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')`

---

Updated

Added `<tbody></tbody>` around `<tr></tr>` elements ; closing `</table>` tags ; `"s"` to `#seafood` element `id` ; adjusted `click` events to two , by utilizing similarity of selectors within `html`

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".orderList").not("#return_li").on("click", function(e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    $("#" + this.id.slice(0, -3) + "s").fadeToggle(500);
    var color = elem.css('background-color');
    console.log(color);
    if (color === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
      elem.css("background-color", "#05FF0A")
    } else {
      elem.css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    }
  });

  $("#return_li").click(function() {
    $(".food_table").fadeIn(500);
    $(this).siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","rgb(255,255,255)")
    })
  });

});
```

```css
.orderList {
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="main">
  <ul class="top_menu">
    <li class="orderList" id="starter_li">Starter</li>
    <li class="orderList" id="soup_li">Soup</li>
    <li class="orderList" id="seafood_li">Seafood</li>
    <li class="orderList" id="return_li">Return All</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="middleBox">
    <table class="food_table" id="starters" style="width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>S1</td>
          <td>Starter1
            <br>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="food_table" id="soups" style="width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Soup1</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="food_table" id="seafoods" style="width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>seafood1</td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: i dun know why it works some part. The toggle function is fine but i m not sure why the green part is not working

Comment: @NicholasAggerLui See updated post, stacksnippets `Return All` to reset `.orderList` to initial styles. Can describe _"i m not sure why the green part is not working"_ ?

Comment: i have seen your updated post. The toogle part is working the return all as well but i did not changed any color when i click on the orderlist

Comment: Thank you so much. It works and i look and the code I understand how it works ! Thank you ! One more thing, if i want the background color white and the font is green  when i click it switch the color. How i can modify it ?